# Find different strings in distinct lines of a file

Tags: shell-script

I have a file which contains the entries of few reports with additional data as follows:

```
04-28-17  05:42AM  8938080 Report1.csv
04-28-17  05:42AM  2291117 Report2.csv
04-28-17  05:43AM  2432822 Report3.csv
```

I have to read each and every line of the file and if the respective size of the file is not matching which can be pre-defined it should throw me an output saying Report1 or Report2 does not have proper size.

Comment: Should we assume the last field is the file name and the penultimate field the file size? Are the fields defined by spaces? Or are those tabs? Can you have file names with spaces?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have too many files and speed is not an issue, you could do this in the shell:

```
while read date time size name; do 
    [[ $(stat -c '%s' -- "$name") -ne "$size" ]] && echo bad $name 
done < file
```